# QGIS Python SQLite using variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I have been looking for answers and working on this for many hours.
In the spatialite database table nodes, id is an integer.

```
    idValToNode = 854

    sql =  'UPDATE nodes SET obsolete = 0 WHERE id = ?'
    cur.execute(sql, idValToNode)
```

ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

```
    idValToNode = 854

    sql =  'UPDATE nodes SET obsolete = 0 WHERE id = ?'
    cur.execute(sql, str(idValToNode))
```

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.

```
    idValToNode = 854

    sql =  'UPDATE nodes SET obsolete = 0 WHERE id = ?'
    cur.execute(sql, idValToNode,)
```

ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

If I place the 854 inside the sql statement and remove the variable, it works fine.
I need to use a variable. Please help. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects), your parameter needs to be a tuple, and Python expects single-element tuples to be constructed like this: `(idValToNode,)`.  That would make your cur.execute() function look more like this:

```
cur.execute(sql, (idValToNode,))
```

Comment: Adding the parenthesis worked great! Glad it was a simple solution. Much appreciated.